# Orbital decay of the Earth's orbit and Earth's moving closer to the Sun

Tags: the-sun, orbit, earth

If we consider orbital decay of the Earth's orbit, then can we counter argue with the following reasons?

1. Due to tidal effects transferring small amounts of angular momentum from the Sun's spin to Earth's orbit, can we conclude that Earth's orbit is actually moving slightly further away from the Sun?
2. Can we say that the orbit is increasing in size because the sun loses millions of tons of mass each day, mostly to the ejection of particles called solar winds?

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19766/as-the-sun-dies-does-the-earths-orbit-change?rq=1 discusses these issues in the context of the long-term future of the solar system. At the moment all of these effects are extremely small. Gravitational interaction with other planets (mainly Jupiter) should also be considered.